# any limit of SQL Server connection count?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise + C# + ADO.Net + .Net 3.5. I am using sp_who2 or sys.dm_exec_connections to find active connections numbers (let me know if my method to find active connection numbers are wrong). For some heavy database consumer application, I can find even active connection count > 1000.

I am wondering whether there are any upper bound limitations of active connection numbers of SQL Server?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is a per-instance, not per database, configuration. You can check the current value in [`sys.configurations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188345.aspx) and change it with [`sp_configure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx). The relevant option is [`user connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187882.aspx):

> Use the user connections option to
>   specify the maximum number of
>   simultaneous user connections allowed
>   on Microsoft SQL Server. The actual
>   number of user connections allowed
>   also depends on the version of SQL
>   Server you are using and the limits of
>   your application or applications and
>   hardware. SQL Server allows a maximum
>   of 32,767 user connections.

1000 of connections is not an exceedingly high number. On high end systems the server can listen on multiple ports [affinitized to NUMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345346(SQL.105).aspx) nodes and have hundreds and thousands of clients connected to each node.

Note that the number of connections is different from the number of *requests*, ie. connections actively executing something, [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx). Each Request requires one or more workers and the number of workers is configured with the [`max worker threads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024.aspx) option.

Comment: Me too :) I always took for granted that 32k+ user slots would never be a concern, but these particulars are really good details.

Comment: Thanks Nissan, I studied the following link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx, my most confusion is -- what is the differences between "Connections per client" and "User connections"?

Comment: 1. I am confused about your comments -- "connections actively executing something, sys.dm_exec_requests". What do you mean "something" here? Do you mean "something" is "sys.dm_exec_requests"? 2. I think the number of connection should be the same as that of requests if MARS is not used. Is that correct understanding? Any comments?

Comment: 'something' means a SQL batch sent to the server (ie. a 'request'). The connections are always present as long as the client keeps the conneciton open. A request is only present from the moment the batch arrived at the server until the result is sent back to the client. Requests are visible in sys.dm_exec_requests.

Comment: Thanks for comments Remus, I am using sp_who2 or sys.dm_exec_connections to find active connections numbers, is that the correct method to count number of active connections?

Comment: define 'active connection'. sp_who will show system tasks (lazuy writer, ghost writer, resource monitor etc) that don't have a conneciton. sys.dm_exec_connections will show connections that don't execute anything. Also sys.dm_exec_connections show non T-SQL conenctions like Mirroring ones, you must filter out base don protocol_type.

Comment: Thanks Nissan, I studied the following link, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx my most confusion is -- what is the differences between "Connections per client" and "User connections"?

Comment: And if you think my two methods to monitor SQL Server active connections are not perfect, I want to learn your perfect method to monitor SQL Server active connections. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I read again the document of sys.dm_exec_connections , and seems it does not say it will show idle connections along with active connections (i.e. no connection status column returned), how do you know "sys.dm_exec_connections will show connections that don't execute anything"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

32,767 is the max limit per database.

I would do it as follows:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*)
FROM
     master.dbo.syslockinfo
WHERE 
     DB_NAME(rsc_dbid) = 'your_database_name'
```

Comment: Is my method of finding active connection number correct? If yes, do you mean the number I find should never exceed 32,767?

Comment: I just want to make sure the connection number I am finding is the same thing as you said. :-)

Comment: From your referred MSDN document, my most confusion is -- what is the differences between "Connections per client" and "User connections"?

Comment: I just did a test using two databases and that max. connections was limited to 16K.  This means that the number isn't per database, it appears to be limited per SQL instance.

Comment: Eve Online has had over 60,000 concurrent users on their unsharded database.