# Why the SQL Server error when many clients are trying to write to a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a simple program on about 200 machines that logs what form the user is opening. Everytime a form is open a Sql connection is opened, a row is inserted and I guess the connection is closed ? I read Connection pooling is on by default so I guess it is not really closing it ? I am not allowed to call a web service or a potential better way so my question is why this error and is there and idea how to fix it ? Or something on the SQL end ? Maybe a setting I can try changing ?

```
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO LoggerLoanForm VALUES(@Session, @Form, @DateStamp, @LoanNumber)", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Session", llf.SesssionId));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Form", llf.Form));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DateStamp", llf.DateStamp));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LoanNumber", llf.LoanNumber));

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppInsightHelper.TrackException(ex);
            }
        }
```

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.)The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

The error seems to happen more during peak hours so I guess there are not enough open connections or something to the SQL server?

Comment: You are using connections property in the app code - the `using` block will close the connection when it's done. I suspect there's something that needs changed on the _server_ side to [allow more simultaneous connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499718) or use a different concurrency model.  You might also have deeper network issues, but with only 200 users it seems unlikely unless you have really cheap switches or routers.

Comment: if you google                    -          A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server intermittent      -             you will see other Q's where people have this problem, many people have mentioned network overloaded, firewall etc etc

Comment: I'd imagine it is network rather than SQL server, if you ran out of connections you'd get a message saying there were no more connections usually - I'm presuming it is intermittent - if you sleep for 100ms after an error, then do an automatic retry for a limited number of times - would that help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about a retry

```
        const int max_try = 5;

        int i = max_try;

        while (i-- > 0)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO LoggerLoanForm VALUES(@Session, @Form, @DateStamp, @LoanNumber)", connection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Session", llf.SesssionId));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Form", llf.Form));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DateStamp", llf.DateStamp));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LoanNumber", llf.LoanNumber));

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        i = 0;
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (i == 0) 
                            AppInsightHelper.TrackException(ex);
                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is a good idea.. Ill try this.. If the problem is congestion then 5 retries should be enough to get through.. I can check the exception log and find out