# sql connection optimization

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I have two questions about use sql server 2008 in c#.

questions 1 : What is the number of simultaneous query for a connection sql server 2005 in c#?

my connection string is :

```
Data Source = localhost;database=TaskQueue;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Connection Timeout=0;Pooling=false;
```

questions 2 : what is Productive lifetime of a connection ? i want to keep open a global connection in the end off runing app and just use for this connection.
Do problems occur with this method?

Comment: you can check this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499718/any-limit-of-sql-server-connection-count

Comment: To answer part 2 see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx Basically, you want your connections to be as short lived as possible so they can be returned to the pool the framework provides already.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the number of simultaneous query for a connection sql server 2005 in c#?

SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition can support a maximum of 32,767 simultaneous connections.

> What is Productive lifetime of a connection ? i want to keep open a global connection in the end off runing app and just use for this connection. Do problems occur with this method?

SQL Server takes advantage of [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) and as such you'll generally want to keep your connections as short-lived as opposed so that they can be returned to the [pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) after use.

So consider wrapping your SQL calls within a `using` statement to ensure they are opened, executed, and properly disposed of as opposed to using a global connection that stays open:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string"))
{
     // Do stuff
}
```

**Check Your Connection String**

It's worth noting that your existing connection string has pooling explicitly disabled, which won't allow you to take advantage of the built-in connection pooling:

```
Data Source = ...; Pooling=false;
```

I'd highly recommend turning this back on unless you absolutely know what you are doing, as otherwise you might experience some unexpected behaviors, orphaned connections, etc.

Comment: when not use Pooling=false; error passing  :
timeout expired the timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Comment: i use the
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your-connection-string"))
{
     // Do stuff
}
but passing the error